# Sorting Problem in date format(mm/dd/yyyy HHMMSS) using YUI

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I won't be able to sort the column which has the date format(mm/dd/yyyy HHMMSS) by using YUI YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatDate

Please help me out on this problem

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, from [YUI dataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/)

> **It expects to hold data in native JavaScript types**. For instance, a date is expected to be a JavaScript Date instance, not a string like "4/26/2005" **in order to sort properly**. Therefore, **the type of the data** (e.g., String, Number, Date, etc.) held in the dataTable **determines the sort algorithm**, not the type as defined in your Column definition formatter property.

Which implies **the formatter property** (used to show data in a human-friendly format) function **has nothing to do with the sorting algorithm**

How does input data is converted ???

> Converting data types as data comes into your dataTable **is enabled through the parser property** in the fields array of your DataSource's responseSchema

You question is not clear. I suppose your data comes as *mm/dd/yyyy HHMMSS*. If so, you need to convert to a plain JavaScript Date (as said above) by using dataSource's parser property

```
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
    fields: [
        {key:"birthDate", parser:function(data) {
            // Convert to native JavaScript objects right here        
        }}
    ]
}
```